# How to turn off localized log messages in JBoss AS 7

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

My IDEs: Eclipse Mars/Oxygen/Photon

During development I use a local installation of JBoss AS 7. The operating system is Windows 10 and the locale is pt-br (brazilian portuguese). Because that, this local instance of JBoss also shows log messages in pt-br, such as:

```
09:13:05,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Criação de serviço de gerenciamento http usando o socket-binding (management-http)
```

Non-english log messages are annoying because they make it harder to find solutions for errors in the internet, like this one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: O unitName persistente não foi especificado e existem definições de unidade ...
```

So, what I ask is: how to make JBoss AS 7 to show all the log messages in Eclipse console in good english?

Comment: You can open the Edit Configuration from JBoss and add this -Duser.language=en  as VM Arguments.

Comment: @awagenhoffer: thanks, but after some minutes trying to find such an option, I could not spot it. Would you please give me some directions?

Comment: The need of switching to english messages is a valid requirement. But it doesn't help you much on searching the internet for help, because it's enought to search for the individuial error number along with its prefix (like JBASxxxxx, UTxxxxx, WFLYWELDxxxx, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf.bat` and add the `-Duser.language=en` to the `JAVA_OPTS`. You can append the following to the file:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en %JAVA_OPTS%"
```

Just as a note too WildFly does not included internationalized log messages.